# Не удаётся отправить приложение в heroku : Failed to detect set buildpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Не получается выложить проект на heroku.
Постоянно пишет:

```
git push heroku master
Counting objects: 84, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (73/73), done.
Writing objects: 100% (84/84), 20.44 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 84 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Failed to detect set buildpack https://codon-         buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/ruby.tgz
remote: More info:     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to alwizo.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/alwizo.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/alw.git'
```

Все необходимые файлы в проекте есть. Buildpacks установлены. 
Не пойму, чего ему не хватает. 
Если кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой, напишите плиз как её решили.
Проект на ruby on rails.
Спасибо!

Comment: *Все необходимые файлы в проекте есть.* -- а непохоже. Приложите список того, что у вас в корне репозитория.

Comment: Сорри, что сразу не ответил. Я написал в тех поддержку heroku и буквально сразу после этого всё заработало. Даже ответ еще от них не пришел. Так что скорее всего проблема была на их стороне.

Comment: Интересно. Ладно, не воспроизводится, так не воспроизводится.